# Formio conditional select

Tags: formio

I use the library formio.js and I'm trying to filter options in a selectbox according to selected value of another selectbox in the form.
I understood how you can do it with external source as described [here](https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/examples/external.html)

But I don't understand how I can do it without external source.
In the example in the link above, you see that the selected value of the first selectbox is passed in the URL that gets the content of the second selectbox server side. But in my situation I can't make the query to the server, I want to filter the data defined directly in the component. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you expand on, "But I don't understand how I can do it without external source?" The example you provided populates the 'Model' select component only when you make a selection via the 'Make' select component. What are you trying to do in your case?

Comment: Thanks @Brandan, I just edited the question to clarify what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     {
  "label": "Columns",
  "columns": [
    {
      "components": [
        {
          "label": "Select",
          "widget": "choicesjs",
          "tableView": true,
          "data": {
            "values": [
              {
                "label": "a",
                "value": "a"
              },
              {
                "label": "b",
                "value": "b"
              },
              {
                "label": "c",
                "value": "c"
              },
              {
                "label": "d",
                "value": "d"
              }
            ]
          },
          "key": "select",
          "type": "select",
          "input": true
        }
      ],
      "width": 6,
      "offset": 0,
      "push": 0,
      "pull": 0,
      "size": "md",
      "currentWidth": 6
    },
    {
      "components": [
        {
          "label": "Select 1",
          "widget": "choicesjs",
          "tableView": true,
          "dataSrc": "custom",
          "data": {
            "custom": "component.data.allValues = {\r\n  a: [\r\n    {\r\n      label: \"Sample A\",\r\n      value: \"sampleA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      label: \"Sample B\",\r\n      value: \"sampleB\"\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  b: [\r\n    {\r\n      label: \"item A\",\r\n      value: \"itemA\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      label: \"item B\",\r\n      value: \"itemB\"\r\n    }\r\n\r\n  ],\r\n  c: [],\r\n  d: []\r\n};\r\n\r\nvalues = data.select ? component.data.allValues[data.select] || [] : [];",
            "allValues": {
              "a": [
                {
                  "label": "Sample A",
                  "value": "sampleA"
                },
                {
                  "label": "Sample B",
                  "value": "sampleB"
                }
              ],
              "b": [
                {
                  "label": "item A",
                  "value": "itemA"
                },
                {
                  "label": "item B",
                  "value": "itemB"
                }
              ],
              "c": [],
              "d": []
            }
          },
          "dataType": "string",
          "refreshOn": "select",
          "clearOnRefresh": true,
          "key": "select1",
          "type": "select",
          "input": true
        }
      ],
      "width": 6,
      "offset": 0,
      "push": 0,
      "pull": 0,
      "size": "md",
      "currentWidth": 6
    }
  ],
  "key": "columns",
  "type": "columns",
  "input": false,
  "tableView": false
}
```

Here we have 2 select components namely select and select 1. second component options are dependent on first component. Store all the available options for second component in a variable `component.data.allValues`. At the end assign the values to the select component as

```
values = data.select ? component.data.allValues[data.select] || [] : [];
```

here `select` is the api key used for first component.

[image]

in second component, data tab configuration, in `Refresh Options On` select the field on which the dropdown options are dependent on. this will refresh the options whenever there is a change in value of first component.

Comment: This is not a feasible option when there are a lot of data in the dependent select control.